# How to shift v-flex elements away from one another in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

in my vuejs application, I have a file called **ProductDetails.vue.** For the template, I used Vuetify to create a grid system where the product's image will be at the left, and the product's content to the right. However, I have encountered **two problems.** **Firstly,** how do i shift the images and content away from one another so that there is space. **Secondly,** how to shift the button to the right most of the product's content. Below is my code, a screenshot of my current design and a screenshot of my desired design.

https://codepen.io/Issaki/pen/qwRWgZ

Update #1: I am still trying to solve this issue, is there anyone that can help me?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 md5 lg5>
          <v-img
            class="white--text"
            height="350px"
            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg"
          />
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 md7 lg7>
          <p class="subheading font-weight-light grey--text text--darken-1 mb-1">Samsung</p>
          <p class="display-1 font-weight-light">OnePlus 3</p>
          <p
            class="subheading"
          >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p class="headline font-weight-medium">$329</p>
          <p class="muted">Inclusive of all taxes. Free home delivery.</p>
          <v-btn color="yellow">
            <v-icon left>shopping_cart</v-icon>Add to Cart
          </v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: Current Design]

[image: Desired Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add space between the two `v-flex` if you simply add some **padding** to one of them. So by adding `class="pl-3"` which translates to `padding-left-3` to the second `v-flex` you can add some space. You can learn more about [spacing helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing).

For the button just wrap it in:

```
<v-layout align-end justify-end>
        <v-btn color="yellow" >
             <v-icon left>shopping_cart</v-icon>Add to Cart
         </v-btn>
</v-layout>
```

You can learn more about it [here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#layout-playground)

**Update**: A better way to add spacing though would be to add `grild-list-*` to your container. In that case it will add some spacing to all your elements in the container so you dont need the added padding anymore. You can see the updated Codepen below and read more [here.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid-lists)

I have forked and edited your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/NmdjWj?editors=1010).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Btw, is there any way  I can contact you if I have further questions (via email or social media)?

Comment: @Issaki please see the update in my solution. It will make your life easier :)

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :>